# Unable to Access DIV element using Watir

Tags: html, ruby, watir

Hi I am trying to access the DIV element using watir but I am unable to do that,I have tried in different ways but couldn't access it,may be I think it need to be access through some parent element can anyone help me out?

```
 My system Configurations
 IE-8
 Windows 7
```

[image]

I tried with the below command
                         `@ie.div(:text,'COMPOSE').click`
the command gets execute with no errors but no action is performed on the UI

Comment: I am trying to access the div element which is highlighted by an arrow

Comment: guyz if you dont know the answers just keep away but dont click on down button or if u think these is the duplicate one then mention the original question

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to locate that element. You need to give some specific details of how you want to be able to locate that element. As well, telling us what you have tried and why they did not work will save everyone time.

Comment: Thank You Very Much TIN TIN for u r warm welcome...............here what I did  @ie.div(:text,'COMPOSE').click, i am trying to click on the 'COMPOSE' button in gmail, I tried with the above statement it gets executed with no errors but no action is performed on the UI.

Comment: @justin can u specify some of the ways which you are aware ...........

Comment: What version of Watir are you actually using - ie Classic or Webdriver? The tags on the question conflict given that you have tagged firewatir, but you mention IE8 and Watir-Webdriver. `@ie.div(:text,'COMPOSE').click` also worked just fine when I tried with Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Watir 1.6.7 is installed in my machine,even I tried with the class and id attributes those statement gets executed well but no action is performed on the UI

Comment: and for your info I am requiring watir but not watir-webdriver

Comment: @khan I do agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution appears to be switching to Watir-Webdriver. With Watir-Webdriver, `@ie.div(:text,'COMPOSE').click` will work as expected.

Assuming that is not an option, there are a couple of reasons why that same command does not work with Watir(-Classic) v1.6.7:

- The first problem is that `@ie.div(:text,'COMPOSE').click` will find the first div that contains this text. This would be one of the ancestors of the div you want. As a result, Watir will send the click event against the wrong element.
- The second problem is that the div is not responding to the onclick event fired by Watir. I am not sure why this problem exists.

To solve the first problem, you will need to be more specific when locating the div. In this case, the "role" attribute can be used since none of the ancestor elements have this attribute. Watir-Classic does not support using the role attribute as a locator. As a result, you will need to create a custom locator using an element collection and the `find` method:

```
@ie.divs.find{ |div| div.attribute_value('role') == 'button' && div.text == 'COMPOSE' }
```

To solve the second problem, it turns out that double clicking does work. While newer versions of Watir-Classic have a `double_click` method implemented, it does not exist in 1.6.7. You can replicate the method by calling the `fire_event` method:

```
.fire_event('ondblclick')
```

Putting it all together, the following will click the compose button:

```
@ie.divs.find{ |div| div.attribute_value('role') == 'button' && div.text == 'COMPOSE' }.fire_event('ondblclick')
```

Comment: These works fine,thanks for the help ,can u please tell me whats is the basic difference between  "fire_event" and "click", even I tried with the "click" the command gets execute perfectly but no action is performed on the UI.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I do not know the reason why `click` does not work in this case.

Comment: k Thanks @Justin Ko ,but you one more to answer after clicking on compose the compose window opens,but I am unable to type the text "I mean the message in the box" even it has div can u suggest how to proceed on these.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one element on the page with the text 'COMPOSE', some may be hidden. Try:

```
@ie.divs(:text,'COMPOSE').size
```

That is divs with an s.
Then you can try something like the following and see if you get a change in the UI:

```
@ie.divs(:text,'COMPOSE').each { |b| b.fire_event('click') }
```

I remember that `fire_event` works better, but would recommend consulting the docs for the difference between `.click` and `fire_event`.

Comment: when I tried with the above command I got the following error  irb(main):012:0> @ie.divs(:text,'COMPOSE').each { |b| b.fire_event('click') }
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
        from (irb):12:in `divs'
        from (irb):12
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630